# Is there a perl or awk solution for this problem?

Tags: awk, perl

I have an input file (**input.txt**) like below.

```
id1      id2       name    weight 
53723848 12651711 timburnes 1.36667
53530214 12651711 timburnes 1.51191
53723848 53530214 timburnes 1.94
764157 52986038 ericcartman 0.861145
56797854 764157 ericcartman 1.35258
56797854 52986038 ericcartman 1.73781
```

Note that **the first line is not part of the actual file, I have added it here for clarity**.

I am trying to extract the values of the `id1` and `id2` to 2 separate files named **unique.txt** and **duplicate.txt**.

If my `weight` column value is greater than 1.5, it means I have **duplicate ids**. In this case, I will move the `id1` value to `unique.txt` file and `id2` value to `duplicate.txt` file.

If my weight column is less than 1.5, it means I do not have duplicate values. So, in this case, I will move both `id1` and `id2` to  **unique.txt** file.

So for the above input, I am expecting the output as,

For **unique.txt** file,

```
53723848 timburnes
764157 ericcartman
56797854 ericcartman
```

For **duplicate.txt** file,

```
12651711 timburnes
53530214 timburnes
52986038 ericcartman
```

I can find out the duplicates using the below code.

To get the values greater than 1.5 based on 4th column,

```
awk -F" " '$4 >= 1.5 { print $1" " $2" " $3" " $4}' file1.txt > Output.txt
```

Now, for values greater than 1.5, I can use the below code to merge the duplicate ids based on their names.

```
  perl -ane 'foreach(@F[0..1]){$k{$F[2]}{$_}++}
           END{
                foreach $v (sort keys(%k)){
                    print "$_ " foreach(keys(%{$k{$v}})); 
                    print "$v\n"
                }; 
            } ' Output.txt
```

However, I am not able to get the output in the way I like in the above approach.

**EDIT**:

I am running the command for my input as below.

```
awk '{
      if ($4 > 1.5) { 
          if (++dup[$2] == 1)  print $2, $3 > "duplicate.txt"
      } 
      else
          if (++uniq[$1] == 1) print $1, $3 > "unique.txt" 
}' << END
17412193 43979400 ericcartman 2.16667
21757330 54678379 andrewruss 0.55264
END
```

I am getting the output as,

```
-bash-3.2$ cat unique.txt
21757330 a.andreev
-bash-3.2$ cat duplicate.txt
43979400 ericcartman
```

However, the output I am expecting is,

```
cat unique.txt
17412193 ericcartman
21757330 andrewruss
54678379 andrewruss
cat duplicate.txt
43979400 ericcartman
```

Comment: What happen if `$4` less than `1.5`?

Comment: @Gnouc, if `$4` is less than 1.5, I will add them to `unique.txt` file. Also, before inserting something to either `unique.txt` or `duplicate.txt` file, I will have to check if the value is already present in the file. If it is already present, I need not insert it again.

Comment: What "add them" means? What happen with `$1` and `$2` when `$4` is less than 1.5?

Comment: @Gnouc, add them means I am appending the values to the `unique.txt` file. So, suppose if `$4` is less than 1.5, I will append `$1` and `$2` to `unique.txt` file.

Comment: "I will have to check if the value is already present" -- which value? Just the ID or the ID/name pair?

Comment: @glennjackman, Just the ID.

Comment: @Ramesh: It means if `$4` < 1.5, both `$1 $3` and `$2 $3` entry will be written to `unique.txt`?

Comment: @Gnouc, yeah you are correct. Basically, `$1` and `$2` corresponds to different ids. I am trying to find if they refer to the same id based on some measures.

Comment: I think if it is your rule, is your output correct? It seems missing `12651711 timburnes` entry in `unique.txt`. The first entry: `53723848 12651711 timburnes 1.36667` has `$4` < 1.5, so both `53723848 timburnes` and `12651711 timburnes` should be in `unique.txt`.

Comment: @Gnouc, But if you see my second row, `$4` is greater than 1.5 and it had `12651711` as the second row in it. So, `12651711` should be removed from `unique.txt` and `53530214` is added to `unique.txt`.

Comment: Please edit and clarify this. Your desired output is not produced by the scripts you show and we have no idea which parts of each line are IDs and which are names or whatever. You show two sets of desired output and they're both different. What do you actually need?

Comment: @terdon, I will update it now. Sorry, for not being clear :)

Comment: @Ramesh: See my answer!

Comment: @terdon, I have updated the question and tried to make it clear. Please let me know if it is not clear :)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still confused. Why are you showing two different desired outputs? Just show us the initial input file and your desired _final_ output file.

Comment: @Terdon, I think Gnouc's solution is what am looking for. Sorry for not explaining things clearly. :) I will try to edit the question and make it more clearer. :)

Comment: Glad you solved it! Might not be that unclear if dsomeone else understood it, I am not at my best right now, I have the flu :(

Comment: Perl is Turing-powerful so, yes, there is a Perl solution. I figure the same holds for Awk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
    $4 < 1.5 {
      uniq[$1] = $3;
      uniq[$2] = $3;
      next;
  }
  {
      uniq[$1] = $3;
      dup[$2] = $3;
      delete uniq[$2];
  }
  END {
    print "--unique.txt--";
    for(i in uniq) {
        print i,uniq[i]
    }
    print "";
    print "--duplicate.txt--";
    for(i in dup) {
        print i,dup[i]
    }
    }' file
--unique.txt--
764157 ericcartman
56797854 ericcartman
53723848 timburnes

--duplicate.txt--
53530214 timburnes
52986038 ericcartman
12651711 timburnes
```

With your second example:

```
$ awk '
    $4 < 1.5 {
      uniq[$1] = $3;
      uniq[$2] = $3;
      next;
  }
  {
      uniq[$1] = $3;
      dup[$2] = $3;
      delete uniq[$2];
  }
  END {
    print "--unique.txt--";
    for(i in uniq) {
        print i,uniq[i]
    }
    print "";
    print "--duplicate.txt--";
    for(i in dup) {
        print i,dup[i]
    }
    }' << END
> 17412193 43979400 ericcartman 2.16667
> 21757330 54678379 andrewruss 0.55264
END
--unique.txt--
21757330 andrewruss
54678379 andrewruss
17412193 ericcartman

--duplicate.txt--
43979400 ericcartman
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible for me to get the values to file? If I use it now, I am getting the output printed in the console and so am not able to check it. :)

Comment: Replace `print i,uniq[i]` by `print i,uniq[i] >> "unique.txt"`. Do the same thing with dup. A note that the output is not sorted.

Comment: I tried that only. I get some syntax error.

Comment: What line causes syntax error?

Comment: Sorry, I was using single quotes for file. I think it should work now with double quotes. Let me check it :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk '{
      if ($4 > 1.5) { 
          if (++dup[$2] == 1)  print $2, $3 > "duplicate.txt"
      } 
      else
          if (++uniq[$1] == 1) print $1, $3 > "unique.txt" 
}' << END
53723848 12651711 timburnes 1.36667
53530214 12651711 timburnes 1.51191
53723848 53530214 timburnes 1.94
764157 52986038 ericcartman 0.861145
56797854 764157 ericcartman 1.35258
56797854 52986038 ericcartman 1.73781
END

$ cat unique.txt 
53723848 timburnes
764157 ericcartman
56797854 ericcartman

$ cat duplicate.txt 
12651711 timburnes
53530214 timburnes
52986038 ericcartman
```

Comment: Please see the edit of my question. I ran your command and pasted the output that am getting.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Perl one:

```
perl -lane '$F[3]>1.5 ? print STDERR "$F[1] $F[2]" : print STDOUT "$F[0] $F[2]"'\
 input.txt 2> duplicate.txt > unique.txt
```

I am not checking for duplicates here, if I understand your question correctly, you have already done so and whether something is a dupe or not depends on the value of the last field. If I am misunderstanding something please let me know and I will update this.

The code above produces

```
$ cat duplicate.txt 
12651711 timburnes
53530214 timburnes
52986038 ericcartman

$ cat unique.txt 
53723848 timburnes
764157 ericcartman
56797854 ericcartman
```

Comment: You solution is only right for these input, it provides the right desired output but with wrong OP's logic. The OP wants `1) if $4 < 1.5, then write both entry ($1 $3) and ($2 $3) to unique.txt` --- `2) if $4 >= 1.5, then write ($1 $3) to unique.txt and write ($2 $3) to duplicate.txt, if $2 was in unique.txt, remove its entry in unique.txt`.

Comment: @Gnouc you may well be right. I honestly have no idea what the OP is asking for at this point. The question is very confusing and I see no relation between the input and the desired output(s). I'll wait for Ramesh to clarify.

Comment: @terdon, am really sorry for pretty confusing question :) I will try and update it clearly in some time. Again, I am sorry for not being clearer :)

Comment: @Ramesh relax! As I said in my previous comment, I have a flu at the moment so it is quite possible that I'm just being obtuse. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: @terdon, oh no. Hope you get well soon :) Is it `MERS` virus?